# Design of Experiments: ANOVA and multiple linear regression

Tags: anova, multiple-regression, experiment-design, regression-coefficients

I have done a fractional design 2^(4-1). I did the ANOVA analysis to determinate factor and interaction effects and contributions an so on and i got the which factors and interactions are affecting my output

Then I did a multiple lineal regresson using design parameters (-1 and 1) and the measured ouput (Excel):

[image]

My interpretation for this lineal regresions is the following:

- Model cant explain the data because F > 0.05
- Any of the parameters considered in the regression are well fitted in the model since its probability is >0.05.

Is this interpretation correct? would you comment anything else?

My main doubt here is, is my DOE analysis using ANOVA correct even if lineal regression is not fitted?

Thank you,

Comment: It appears that you have 8 cases (n=8) and 6 terms in the regression model. This leaves you with 1 degree of freedom remaining for the residual. It is no wonder that the F is not significant even though R-squared is very large (.83). You don't have enough data to fit this model. The above results are meaningless.